# MAC OSX-Write Xcode .Dylib to use in JNA (Java Native Access ) -JAVA

Tags: java, xcode, macos, jna, dylib

Till now i was using dll file with JNA in windows successfully. I had created dll in VC++ successfully which then loaded in Java using JNA. 
But now i have requirement where i need to provide same software in Mac Os also.

as I have not worked with mac os and Xcode i don't know how to create .dylib.

Here is what i have tried so far using Google and other resources.

1)Opened Xcode, selected "create a new Xcode project"

2)Selected Framework & library , and clicked C/C++ Library

3)I gave Project Name as SimpleDylib and choose Type as Dynamic and pressed next.

4)then i added new file, a C++ file to this project and gave name as SimpleDylib.cpp

5) I wrote a simple function

`int addNumber(int a,int b)
    { 
    return a+b;
    }`

From here i don't know  how to export this function. Like in windows VC++ i use .def file to export the function successfully. And in java using jna i am able to use this dll and function inside dll successfully.

in Xcode i tried to use

`#define EXPORT _attribute__((visibility("default")))
      EXPORT 
    int addNumber(int a,int b)
    { 
    return a+b;
    }`

but still i was not able to use this dylib in Java and i get error as

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkeError: Error lloking up function 'addNumber' : dlsym(0x7fb930d49930,addNumber) : symbol not found

**So how do i export function from dylib? Did my above steps are correct so far? What is the way to create .dylib which can be loaded and use in JNA-JAVA.**

Comment: If you look at the build for JNA itself, it generates a shared library called "testlib" for all platforms on which JNA runs (including OSX).

Comment: In addition to JNA, you could also give [JavaCPP](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) a try: We can have it compile the C++ file and build the library file as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is a `.cpp` file then you're undoubtably suffering from `C++` name mangling.

You need to add `extern "C"` to the export like:

```
extern "C" EXPORT int addNumber(int a,int b)
```

To verify if the routine is mangled or not, you can look at the .dylib using nm, a mangled version of the routine would look like: `__Z9addNumberii` while an unmangled version would look like `_addNumber`.

Additionally, on OSX, the preferred extension for shared libraries that are used with JNI/JNA are `.jnilib`, not `.dylib`, but they're identical in all but file extension